# Opencv Different Outputs with imshow and imwrite

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I read two images into numpy arrays using open cv. I tried two different equations for adding these images

Equation 1:
    img = (img_one/2) + (img_two/2)

Equation 2:
    img = (0.5*img_one) + (0.5*img_two)

Equation 1 outputs image as expected, but Equation 2 outputs an image completely unexpected.

Here's my code (python2):

```
import numpy as np
from cv2 import *

tiger = imread('tiger.jpg')
nature = imread('nature.jpg')

mul_img = 0.5*tiger + 0.5*nature
div_img = tiger/2 + nature/2

imshow('mul_image', mul_img) 
imshow('div_image', div_img)
waitKey(0)
destroyAllWindows()
```

Original images used:

[image: Tiger image]

[image]

The images generated are as follows:

[image: division image]

[image: multiplication image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference of output is not due to using operator `*` or `/`, but due to `cv2.imshow()`, In the first case when you use `mul_img = 0.5*tiger + 0.5*nature` The `dtype` of returned matrix implicitly converted to `floar32`, because you used floating number as one of the operands. But in the second case, The `dtype` of both the matrix and `number` is `int` only, So the `dtype` of the returned matrix from `div_img = tiger/2 + nature/2` would be of type `uint8`.

Now `cv2.imshow()` has some serious issues while rendering 4-channel RGBA images, it ignores the alpha channel or rendering Mat with floating point numbers, etc. Now you are left with 2 solutions:

- Use `cv2.imwrite()` to debug the images:

  ```
  cv.imwrite("path/to/img.jpg", mul_img)
  ```
- Convert the image to `uint8` before `cv2.imshow()`

  ```
  mul_img = mul_img.astype(np.uint8)
  ```

Comment: thanks, that also explains why the correct images were getting generated while using imwrite.