# How to get original image after storing as HDF5?

Tags: opencv, keras, hdf5

I'm training a CNN using Keras fit_generator on a large data set (> 50k images).  I read the images using cv2, do some preprocessing (rotate,resize) and write to a HDF5 file (following [this](http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/hdf5/hdf5.html) tutorial). My problem is the image read from HDF5 looks different from the original preprocessed image before writing to HDF5. Code for saving HDF5 file -

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
import os
import random
import h5py

all_imgs = os.listdir(r"D:\test_images/")
img_rows, img_cols = 128, 128

hdf5_path = r'D:\test_images\test.hdf5'

train_shape = (len(all_imgs),3 , img_rows, img_cols)

hdf5_file = h5py.File(hdf5_path, mode='w')
hdf5_file.create_dataset("train_img", train_shape, np.int8)
hdf5_file.create_dataset("train_mean", train_shape[1:], np.float32)

mean = np.zeros(train_shape[1:], np.float32)
for i in range(len(all_imgs)):
    img = cv2.imread(r"D:\test_images/"+all_imgs[i])
    img = imutils.rotate(img,90)
    img = cv2.resize(img,(128,128))
    if i == 0:
        cv2.imwrite(r"D:\test_images/test_before.jpg",img)

    img = np.rollaxis(img, 2) #My CNN takes input with channel first

    hdf5_file["train_img"][i, ...] = img[None]
    mean += img / float(len(all_imgs))

hdf5_file["train_mean"][...] = mean
hdf5_file.close()
```

Code for reading from HDF5 file -

```python
hdf5_path = r'D:\test_images\test.hdf5'

hdf5_file = h5py.File(hdf5_path, "r")
images = hdf5_file["train_img"][0:1, ...]
images = images.astype('float32')
# images /= 255
images = np.moveaxis(images, 1, -1)
cv2.imwrite(r"D:\test_images/test_after.jpg",images[0])
hdf5_file.close()
```

The original image, image before writing to HDF5 and image read from HDF5 - 
[image: Original Image]
[image: Preprocessed image before writing to HDF5]
[image: Image after reading from HDF5]

During prediction, if I pass the image read from cv2, it's not giving correct results. However saving the image as HDF5 and passing the image read from this HDF5 file gives correct output. How to handle this either during saving HDF5 or during prediction?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my code and solution with help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41531081/5235376) SO answer. While creating data set in HDF5, I'd defined datatype as np.int8 (  Byte (-128 to 127))

```
hdf5_file.create_dataset("train_img", train_shape, np.int8)
```

Changing it to np.uint8 (Unsigned integer (0 to 255)) corrected the result

```
hdf5_file.create_dataset("train_img", train_shape, np.uint8)
```