# Can't get CV2.IMSHOW() to display the same as CV2.IMWRITE()

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, imshow

This one has bothered me for a while today, and the solution of writing to disk then reading it back is just not a good one given i would want to see how things are on screen iteratively before i save it.

the code below is to illustrate the problem in the smallest amount of code

I import numpy and CV2 as normal, with no issues
Then create a empty numpy array for a color image this way (black background)

```
Xsize = Ysize = 100
img_np = np.zeros([Xsize,Ysize,3])
```

The following lines are for illustration coloring select pixels gray in BGR

```
img_np[1][1] = [1, 1, 1]
img_np[1][3] = [10, 10, 10]
img_np[1][5] = [20, 20, 20]
img_np[1][7] = [30, 30, 30]
img_np[1][9] = [40, 40, 40]
img_np[1][11] = [100, 100, 100]
img_np[1][13] = [200, 200, 200]
img_np[1][15] = [240, 240, 240]
```

this issue happens whether i resize or not..

```
img_cv = cv2.resize(img_np,(1000,1000), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
cv2.imshow('name',img_cv)
cv2.imwrite('crawltest.png', img_cv)
```

the cv2.imshow comes out like this:

[image]

while cv2.imwrite comes out like this:

[image]

for those that maybe cant see cause they wont let my images appear:
the imshow image test pixels are all white on a black field
the imwrite image test pixels are the correct grey scale values

totally has me perplexed... 
do note that even if i do not resize, and just use the numpy array, its the same results
[and i am writing using jupyter notebooks in case that has anything to do with it, though it shouldn't]

any ideas?

Comment: `mul_img = mul_img.astype(np.uint8)` before imshow should work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530917/opencv-different-outputs-with-imshow-and-imwrite

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `dtype` when initializing the data

```
img_np = np.zeros([Xsize,Ysize,3], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Stupendous quick answer... perfect... thank you very much!

Is there a reason you need to do this for imshow, but not imwrite? just asking as a curious person.